# Makefile ifeq compare output from shell

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to compare output from evaluated value on a Makefile ( GNU make ). However, even when the echo-ed value is `0`, the `ifeq` block not consider it is equal if I just put `0` as the comparator.

But if I put following as a comparator `$(shell echo 0)`, then `ifeq` will accept it as an equal value.

To be clear, following is a "mock" what I am going to achieve ( keep in mind that `$(eval ZERO_VALUE := $(shell echo 0))` is just a "mockup", there will a command replacing `$(shell echo 0))` there, which will output `0` at some point.

```
zero-test:

    $(eval ZERO_VALUE := $(shell echo 0))
    echo "Echo-ed value: ${ZERO_VALUE}"

ifeq ($(ZERO_VALUE),$(shel echo 0))
    echo "1st approach Value is zero"
else
    echo "1st approach Value is not zero"
endif

ifeq ($(ZERO_VALUE),0)
    echo "2nd approach Value is zero"
else
    echo "2nd approach Value is not zero"
endif
```

The output when doing `make zero-test` would be:

```
Echo-ed value: 0
1st approach Value is zero
2nd approach Value is not zero
```

**Finally, my main questions are:**

- Why `($(ZERO_VALUE),0)` is not considered equal while the "echo-ed" value is actually `0`?
- Is it possible to have my 2nd approach work? Just feel more natural with that :)

In addition, following is my `make -v` output:

```
❯ make -v       
GNU Make 4.3
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Answer (score 1):

I see several problems:

- You assign the variable within a recipe, then try test it outside the recipe. That just won't work.
- You try read the variable within the same recipe. Without ONESHELL each line in a recipe is run in a separate subshell, meaning no variable settings persist.
- You use eval to assign the variable. That's not how you (should) do it.
- You misspelled "shel".

Attempts to fix above problems:

```
# Set outside recipe for ifeq to work right
ZERO_VALUE := $(shell echo 0)

zero-test:
    echo "Echo-ed value: ${ZERO_VALUE}"

# Fix "shel" typo
ifeq ($(ZERO_VALUE),$(shell echo 0))
    echo "1st approach Value is zero"
else
    echo "1st approach Value is not zero"
endif

ifeq ($(ZERO_VALUE),0)
    echo "2nd approach Value is zero"
else
    echo "2nd approach Value is not zero"
endif
```

If you must communicate ZERO_VALUE within the recipe you should consider either using ONESHELL, or use files instead of variables since they persist across subshell invocations.

```
# Beware of accidental unquoted expansions...
.ONESHELL:
zero-test:
    ZERO_VALUE="$$(echo 0)"
    echo "Echo-ed value: $$ZERO_VALUE"
```

Comment: Assigning variables with `eval` and reading them in the same recipe is viable. Not sure if it's a good idea though.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, as in my case, the `eval` inside recepie won't work if used in `ifeq`. It just works fine if when do `echo` for it.

Comment: @Andreas, I am expecting that the value is set inside a recipe actually. Could you please give a solution by using ONESHELL? I really can't make it work with ONESHELL.

Comment: @Bayu Added a sample, no idea whether it works. Personally I'd go for files because the ONESHELL caveats always gets me, but then making an example would take longer and I just don't feel like it rn.

Comment: @Bayu *"eval inside recepie won't work if used in ifeq"* That's because `ifeq` is not "inside" the recipe. `$(if ...)` would be inside.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, you are right, I realized this a few minutes after my comment above :). That is a nice trick to have `$(if ...)`. What that not cross my mind :D. I will try that, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Andreas, you are right. Using the native Makefile way is painful. Switch to a shell script now and save my time :)